# Filter changes by comment

Tags: wikipedia-api

Are there any way to filter changes by comment (e.g. changes containing some word)?

I want something similar to [`meta=query&list=recentchanges`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brecentchanges) api, but with ability to filter changes by comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, comments are not indexed.

You could write your own code for it, of course - on a smallish wiki unindexed queries would work fine, especially if you limit it to the recentchanges table (last 30 days only). Or you can have client-side logic iterate through the API and filter it.